# AngularJS Error :Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I'm trying to make a service call from angular js. I downloaded the [angular seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).And inside the `view1.js` wrote the following code to call the service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])
.factory('Entry', ['$resource',function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8000/emp/'); // Note the full endpoint address
}])
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['Entry',function(Entry) {
  var entries = Entry.query(function() {
    console.log(entries);
  });
}]);
```

Here is the `index.html` where I have included the required scripts:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But on running the app, it shows the following error in the browser console:

```
    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.view1 due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: try `['Entry',function(Entry) {`

Comment: well that seems to throw another error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Entry`

Comment: add `ngResource` to `angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])`

Comment: Can you include the HTML code in the question.

Comment: Try angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])

Comment: @ArunGhosh thnks I got it working ...actually it was spelling mistake in `app.js` :)

Answer (score 9):

```
<script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that makes sense is that the angular-resource.js file isn't loaded properly, can you have a look at the network tab and see what file is actually loaded and what the name of the module is? to make sure you typed it in correctly.

(Sorry for not commenting, not enough rep yet).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing dependency list.

If you're passing an array as dependeny to be injected, you need to tell angular.

`['Entry', function (Entry) { }];` should do the trick, or just do `function (Entry) { }`.

the reason why `Entry` is undefined, is because angular does not know what u need to be injected (you're passing an array notation to the angular's DI system)

ps: sry for bad english

Comment: @iJay sry for late reply, i see `<script src="angular-resource.js"></script>` is it the right path? because most of angularjs path in your html seems to be in `bower_components` directory :)